# Index .docx type documents using apache poi

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm implementing an indexer to read .docx type documents using Apache poi plugging. The code which I have done is below

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData.data));
XWPFWordExtractor msWord2007Extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
                wordText = msWord2007Extractor.getText();
```

When I'm executing this from line 1, I'm getting below exception.

> org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: Cannot resolve type for handle _XY_Q=space|R=space@http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.cttext7f5btype) - code 13
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.readHandle(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2021)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.readTypeRef(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2095)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.loadAttribute(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2922)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.readAttributeData(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2914)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.finishLoadingType(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2531)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.resolveHandle(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:3507)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaComponent$Ref.getComponent(SchemaComponent.java:104)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType$Ref.get(SchemaType.java:872)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaPropertyImpl.getType(SchemaPropertyImpl.java:92)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeImpl.createElementType(SchemaTypeImpl.java:965)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.create_element_user(XmlObjectBase.java:893)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.getUser(Xobj.java:1657)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.getUser(Cur.java:2654)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.getObject(Cur.java:2647)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._getObject(Cursor.java:995)
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.getObject(Cursor.java:2904)
>       at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph.(XWPFParagraph.java:90)
>       at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:146)
>       at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
>       at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:123)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.samples.handler.MSWordIndexer.getIndexedDocument(MSWordIndexer.java:42)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.indexDocument(SolrClient.java:178)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.doWork(AsyncIndexer.java:203)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.run(AsyncIndexer.java:189)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This happens when the document contains some value. It indexed fine for an empty document.

Comment: for me it is working with tomcat but having some issue with weblogic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could resolve the problem by reimporting poi-ooxml-schemas jar.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception while running my application in Weblogic. The poi-ooxml-schemas was packaged in the ear as applib, but the problem still didn't go away.

I came across with the solution in [Alfresco Jira](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-9049), which I post here for future reference.

The solution was to add hints for the classloader to prefer application packages:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLCONFIG.*</package-name>
    <package-name>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLLANG.*</package-name>
    <package-name>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLSCHEMA.*</package-name>
    <package-name>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sXMLTOOLS.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```